# Sort 'Drop Down List Content Control' form Alphabetically in WORD 2013

Tags: microsoft-word, worksheet-function, microsoft-word-2013

I'm using word 2013. I've created a drop down list using 'Drop-Down List Content Control' in the developer tab, but I can't seem to sort the drop down selections by Alphabetical order. Is this even possible?

Answer (score 0):

Select your control and go to development tab - controls - properties.
Here you can manually change the order of items. Considering the number of options it'll take time, but unfortunately I don't know any better solution.

Comment: Thanks, i was aware of this but like you mentioned its very time consuming, I didn't realise there wasn't a way to sort alphabetically before placing the selections in.